# How to save the elements of multidimensional list in nested json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I have a multidimensional list which looks like below:

```
[
   ['Name1','5','6','7'],
   ['Name2','3','8','5'],
]
```

As you can see, in the above multidimensional list, we have two lists with two names and their values. This generated by an algorithm which can generate more names like 4 names thus, there might be 4 lists inside the multidimensional list.

Based on this I have to save the above info in a json, which looks like below:

```
{
    "id": "id",
    "Values": [
        {
            "Name": "Name1",
            "X": "85",
            "Y": "78",
            "Z": "10"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Name2",
            "X": "85",
            "Y": "78",
            "Z": "10"
        }

    ]
}
```

So all the name will go inside `['Values']['Name']` followed by the int numbers but I am getting confused as to how to save list items in json as it is not fixed. can anyone help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
L = [['Name1','5','6','7'],
     ['Name2','3','8','5']]

keys = ('Name', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')

d = {**{'id': 'id'},
     **{'Values': [dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in L]}}
```

**Result**

```
print(d)

{'Values': [{'Name': 'Name1', 'X': '5', 'Y': '6', 'Z': '7'},
            {'Name': 'Name2', 'X': '3', 'Y': '8', 'Z': '5'}],
 'id': 'id'}
```

**Explanation**

- The syntax `{**d1, **d2}` is used to combine two dictionaries.
- `dict(zip(keys, i))` creates a dictionary mapping the items in `keys` to the elements of `i`, aligning by index.
- A list comprehension is used to iterate over sublists in `L`.

Comment: Thank you very much. But can you explain a bit. I didn't get what you are doing in the code

Comment: @SAndrew, Sure, I've added an explanation.